Interpretation of the Implication Sign
According to @DanChristensen: “Smoking has been scientifically proven to cause cancer. We cannot infer from this that smoking implies cancer.” To this I would reply with the following: First, if we consider the statement: “Smoking implies cancer”, why isn’t the implication sign not treated as a primitive, i.e. why isn’t the implication sign treated as something irreducible to any other sign in logic? Second: Why is the statement “Smoking implies cancer” interpreted in terms of truth and falsity rather than in terms of satisfiability? By this I mean why isn’t the statement “Smoking implies cancer” interpreted as follows: If X smokes is satisfiable, then X having cancer is satisfiable?

Because implication has a standard meaning, the material conditional and its refinements, and it is what it is. If people wish to mean something else they can use different words to express it. For example, "smoking positively correlates with cancer."

@Conifold, I get that, but the standard interpretation doesn’t even have an adequate definition of what truth is or what makes a statement true. And I am afraid as to what a Mathematician would say on the matter.

What the truth is or what makes a statement true is completely irrelevant to what implication is supposed to do - preserve the truth, whatever that is. And mathematicians are the first ones to want it this way. They are concerned with theorems being implied by the axioms, not with what makes the axioms "true". The standard implication is what it is because its neutrality makes it useful to people with all those diverging ideas about "truth".

Implies is when a is true, then b is always true, no more. In medicine we try to determine a possible cause, etiology. This is a different purpose.

@AUTISTINC: The standard interpretation is that truth is undefinable on the natural numbers and thus undefinable in general. Implication has to be about something deeper and more structural than the idea of truth.

Implication has a number of different but related senses. In logic we often wish to use the term to indicate a sufficient, but not necessary condition. So, at its simplest, "A implies B" states that we have a license from logic to infer B from A.
The simplest kind of implication relation is the material implication or material conditional. The material conditional is a truth function, which means it has a truth value that depends only on the truth values of A and B. It does not express any other kind of connection between A and B. A and B might be entirely irrelevant to one another.
This serves to explain why implication differs from causation. When we say A causes B we are talking about a physical relationship that can be described using scientific laws. Causal relations are typically neither necessary nor sufficient. Smoking causes cancer, but you can smoke and not get cancer, and you can get cancer without smoking. To say that smoking causes cancer is not merely a statement of correlation but a claim based on an understanding of the physical and chemical mechanisms by which the products of burning tobacco result in cancerous cells.
Implication needs to be related to other connectives in logic, because it is important to understand under what conditions "A implies B" is true or not. In the case of the material conditional of classical logic, it is true except when A is true and B is false. In other logics, the implication relation has different criteria. For example, in intuitionistic logic it provides a guarantee that if A is constructively provable then so is B. In relevance logics, implication requires a relevant logical connection between A and B. There are also conditionals that are designed to express more complex relationships between A and B such as uncertain inference or counterfactual conditions.
I'm not sure what you mean by 'satisfiability'. In logic we usually use the term to indicate that a formula is true under some interpretation. So "X smokes" is satisfiable simply because there is at least one person who smokes, and "X has cancer" is satisfiable because there is at least one person who has cancer, and both hold conjunctively because there is at least one person who both smokes and has cancer. This would not be adequate to explain the meaning of causation. There have been several attempts to describe a logic of causal relations. Probably the most comprehensive is that of Judea Pearl in his book, Causality (second edition, 2009).
